# Why loop break in first loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, drupal-7

My Goal is to list all lesser user based on role weight, example if user U1 has role of R1 with the weight of 10, and U2 has R2 with weight of 2 and U3 has R3 with weight 5. The output will be (U1, U2) (U1, U3) (U3, U2) and (U2, Null). List all the lesser user on the first row but it seems that in breaks in first loop. Here's my code thank you

```
 <?php
 $uids = array(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
 $result = db_query("SELECT u.uid, u.rid, r.name, r.weight FROM {role} r INNER JOIN      {users_roles} u ON u.rid = r.rid WHERE u.uid IN (:uids)", array(':uids' => $uids));
 $i = 0;
 for ($i = 0; $role = $result->fetchAssoc(); ++$i) {
    print $role['uid'].',';
       foreach($result as $urole) {
         if ($role['weight'] > $urole->weight) {
           echo '(' . $role['uid'] . ',' . $urole->uid  . ')';        
         } 
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the while and not the for loop?

Comment: `$role = $result->fetchAssoc()` in the for loop is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
$role = $result->fetchAssoc()
```

is actually not breaking the loop. I do guess the foreach ($result.... ) is.. Although it is not common to use, I think changing the foreach on $result on line 7 is actually faulty manipulating the $result variable making the very next fetchAssoc() returning false.

I do suggest do use a while loop instead as Shankar already said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $uids = array(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
 $result = db_query("SELECT u.uid, u.rid, r.name, r.weight FROM {role} r INNER JOIN      {users_roles} u ON u.rid = r.rid WHERE u.uid IN (:uids)", array(':uids' => $uids));
 $i = 0;
 while ($role = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    print $role['uid'].','; 
       foreach($result->fetchObject() as $urole) {
         if ($role['weight'] > $urole->weight) {
           echo '(' . $role['uid'] . ',' . $urole->uid  . ')';        
         } 
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop ends when the second condition in the head is true:

```
for ($i = 0; $role = $result->fetchAssoc(); ++$i) {
```

But an assignment ($role = $result->fetchAssoc()) is ALWAYS true, you need to make a comparisation here when the for loop should end.

But you dont know how many result sets you have except you ask for num_rows so a for loop is not the best solution here, try while:

```
while($role = $result->fetchAssoc() != false) {

}
```

and if you need a counter do it manually:

```
$c = 0;
while($role = $result->fetchAssoc() != false) {
    $c++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop into a while loop:

```
while ($role = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
     print $role['uid'].',';
     foreach($role as $urole) {
     if ($role['weight'] > $urole->weight) {
       echo '(' . $role['uid'] . ',' . $urole->uid  . ')';        
     } 
  }
}
```